# Dropdown list not showing selected value

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, dropdown

I have a dropdown list that gets its value from firebase and when I'm trying to pick a value, it shows me an error.

```
There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: vff. 
Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value
'package:flutter/src/material/dropdown.dart':
Failed assertion: line 850 pos 15: 'items == null || items.isEmpty || value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                return item.value == value;
              }).length == 1'
```

here's the source code, I was adding values to dropdown list by using loop, and giving value by name of query

```
return StreamBuilder<List<CoursesRecord>>(
      stream: queryCourseRecord(
        queryBuilder: (courseRecord) => courseRecord.orderBy(/*widget.orderBy*/'${widget.orderBy}', descending: true), limit: 5,
      ),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        // Customize what your widget looks like when it's loading.
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: FlutterFlowTheme.primaryColor,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        List<CoursesRecord> listViewCourseRecordList = snapshot.data;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      String value = listViewCourseRecordList[i].name;
      courseItems.add(
        DropdownMenuItem(
          child: Container(
              width: 316  ,
              child: CourseBoxName(coursesRecord: listViewCourseRecordList[i],)),
          value: value,
        ),
      );
    }
    // Customize what your widget looks like with no query results.
    if (snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
      return Container(
        height: 100,
        child: Center(
          child: Text('No results.'),
        ),
      );
    }
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 100,
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: ButtonTheme(
          alignedDropdown: true,
          child: DropdownButton(
            value: selected,
            isDense: true,
            items: courseItems,
            hint: Text(
              "Выберите курс",
            ),
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                selected = newValue;
                widget.courseSelected(newValue);
              });
            },
            isExpanded: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

So what can I do to fix this problem, I have stuck with it already for several hours T_T

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you keep adding items to a list with every build without clearing it

on first build you add 1,2,3 and the list contains [1,2,3]
on second build you add the same items even though they didn't change, and the list contains [1,2,3,1,2,3] which clearly contains duplicates

remove `courseItems` field and the for loop, then tweak the button definition like following:

```dart
DropdownButton(
  value: selected,
  isDense: true,
  items: [
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
      DropdownMenuItem(
        child: Container(
            width: 316,
            child: CourseBoxName(
              coursesRecord: listViewCourseRecordList[i],
            )),
        value: value,
      )
  ],
  hint: Text(
    "Выберите курс",
  ),
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      selected = newValue;
      widget.courseSelected(newValue);
    });
  },
  isExpanded: false,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got null value so for check conditions like droupdownvalue ?? "xyz"

So you can see XYZ when you got a null value.